# CheckedTextView not clickable

Tags: android, checkedtextview

Hi i setup a CheckedTextView but I can't get the onClick event functioning.
I put the onClick code in the onCreate of the main.layout but I get a nullpointer at line 101, which is chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener().
The Listview is created in the onPostExecute of a AsyncTask.
Can someone please help?

My CheckedTextView:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
         android:id="@+id/listCheckboxview"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="left"  
         android:textColor="#0075AB"  android:textStyle="bold"  android:textSize="14dip" 
         android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"   
         android:clickable="true" 
         android:focusable="true" 
         android:text=""  
         />
```

My onClick event:

```
CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.listCheckboxview); 
        chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { 
            ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle(); 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I put the onClick code in the onCreate of the main.layout but i get a nullpointer at line 101, which is chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

This means that `chkBox` is `null`, which means that Android is not finding `R.id.listCheckboxview`. Make sure you are calling `findViewById()` on the right thing (here, you appear to be calling it on the activity, but your question mentions a `ListView`). Also, try cleaning your project (Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu, or `ant clean` from the command line), as sometimes the `R` constants get out of sync.

Comment: HI Commonsware, i don`t understand the CheckedTextView is part of the listview so i have to do CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.listCheckboxview).
In other words i add the checkboxes in the listview, which is part of a baseadapter by the way.
Any other way to solve this?
Thx.

Comment: @Lars: "the CheckedTextView is part of the listview so i have to do CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.listCheckboxview)" -- if the `CheckedTextView` is a row for your `ListView`, you should not be calling `findViewById()` on the activity. Please read http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf -- a free excerpt from one of my books that covers creating custom `ListView` rows like this. Either you do not need to call `findViewById()` at all (because the row you are inflating/recycling *is* the `CheckedTextView`) or you call it on the inflated/recycled row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) with a null background and a null button. ToggleButton component has another interesting feature that is setting a text to its On state and another one to its Off state. In the example bellow I've also included a selector to the text color.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/toggle_text"
    android:textOn="My on state"
    android:textOff="My off state" />
```

*toggle_text.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/app_color" />

    <item
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</selector>
```